# Given a string of arithmetic expression, find the decimal value of the expression.

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures, expression

An interview question.

Given a string of arithmetic expression, find the decimal value of the expression.

e.g . given

```
 30*(5+10) is a string, its value is 450.
```

My idea:

parse each symbol one by one and rebuild the string as an expression with priority of operators. But, it is not efficient, it is O(n^2) or even worse.

Better ideas ?

thanks

Comment: Stacks:http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/280425

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the expression into postfix using stack in O(n) time.

Then evaluate the postfix expression with stack in O(n) time.

Converting to Postfix is required for determining the priority of operators during the expression evaluation.

Refer evaluation of arithmetic expressions with stack http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/~rkline/DS/deque-stack-algorithms.html

Answer (score 0):

parse and tokenize the string with a finite state automaton:

integer -> integer-token

operator -> operator token

opening-bracket -> state - new expression

closing-bracket -> state - close expression

that way you could just build the tree and execute by flattening the tree bottum up.

Answer (score 0):

Describe the operation in the terms of the trade: Build or find a parser for arithmetic expressions, parse the string, evaluate the abstract syntax tree (AST) and return the result. Since arithmetic expressions are context-free languages and in `LL(1)`, this is possible in `O(n)`. Building a parser is cheap with Boost.Spirit or `yacc`.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the string `"print "` before the expression wrapped in an extra pair of parenthesis, put a semicolon at the end and pass it to perl -e, i.e. in C:

```
system("perl -e 'print (30*(5+10));'");
```